# How can I serialize list of booleans in django rest framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I want my data to be stored like this:
`'days': [True, True, False, True, False, False, False]` as one of the returned fields.

I would like to have a seriaizer:

```py
class HistorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = serializers.BooleanField(many=True)
```

but `serializers.BooleanField` doesn't have 'many' argument.
I've tried doing this:

```py
class DaysListField(serializers.ListField):
    day = serializers.BooleanField()

class HistorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = DaysListField()
```

but it produces:

```py
'days': [{'day': True}, {'day': True}, {'day': False}, {'day': False}, {'day': False}, {'day': False}, {'day': False}]
```

I also tried doing this:

```py
class HistorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_days(self, obj) -> List[bool]:
        return obj.days
```

but Swagger produces an incorrect output of the `days` type, it says it should be `boolean` instead of `[boolean]`.

What is the best way to process this list correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `SerializerMethodField()` is a good way to do this. Alter django query part of the example to return a list.

```
class HistorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_days(self, obj):
        return list(obj.days.value_list('day', flat=True))
```